# Configuring vsftpd for multiple users

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 VM that I want to use as an SFTP server. I installed and configured vsftpd and it works, just not the way I want.

I want to have 2 users - UserA and UserB. Both are only allowed to use their home directory, they can FTP files to sub-directories but are NOT allowed to "cd .." and move above their home directory.

At the moment my vsftpd.conf looks like this

```
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

No matter what options I choose I do this:

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
```

and test and both users can "cd .." and freely move around the FTP server.

How do I restrict these users?

Comment: see: https://serverfault.com/questions/544850/create-new-vsftpd-user-and-lock-to-specify-home-login-directory

Comment: Yes, I feel like I've tried every option, but it still doesn't work :(

I make the changes to the conf file, restart the service, create a new FTP session and the user can navigate to anywhere on the vm

Comment: The link has `chroot_local_user=YES`, this should help, ( Maybe read something about [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) ? )

Comment: As per your link ....
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

NO usernames in the list_file

then I restart vsftpd and test ... user can navigate everywhere :(